# SSL and/or TLS Errors

Tags: r, git, ssl, curl

I'm on Mac OSX 10.13.6

If I do:

```
library("devtools")
install_github(repo = "bryanhanson/ChemoSpec@master")
```

I get the following error:

> install_github(repo = "bryanhanson/ChemoSpec@master") Downloading
>   GitHub repo bryanhanson/ChemoSpec@master from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/bryanhanson/ChemoSpec/zipball/master
>   Installation failed: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I get similar but not identical errors if I try to use `pkgdown::build_site()` but for now let's set that aside; I think it will prove to arise from the same problem.

I've done a lot of research, and I think the error must reside with one or more of the following: `curl`, `git` and/or `openssl`.  I know Mac has its own versions of `openssl` and `curl`, and one might need to take steps to access them.  My `git` is up-to-date (2.19.0), I have used `Homebrew` to update everything it wants to update.  This includes `curl` and `openssl` but `Homebrew` does not automatically link to it so as to avoid interfering with the native Mac versions (They are "keg-only").  I have however within `R` put the `Homebrew` versions on the path and it doesn't fix the error.  `R` and all `R` packages are up-to-date.

My research shows this problem has plagued others but none of the solutions have worked.  It appears as though the problem is related to deprecated protocols, for instance I've set  `git config --global --add http.sslversion=tlsv1.2` to no avail.

Finally, this arose about a month ago but I don't know what I did that caused it.

Sorry this is not much to go on.  Hopefully some of you experts will know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: There is no directory bryanhanson/ChemoSpec@master -- try bryanhanson/ChemoSpec

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: I got no error either. Since master is the default branch, no need to specify it, then the install works.

Comment: I may not have been clear: I expect the `install_github` works fine for everyone else, the problem is with my machine.

Comment: I'm guessing that something is convincing your system to use TLS 1.0, which is no longer supported. What that *something* is, is a mystery, though.

Comment: @torek Exactly!  I just can find where that is...

Comment: Possibly related, but from July: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1703

Comment: @torek That's a good clue, esp. "The macOS Sierra 10.12.6 update updates the curl version from 7.51.0 to 7.54.0, so this behavior regresses when updating from macOS 10.12.5 to 10.12.6" That could have been when my problem arose.  But, I have curl 7.41.0 and the command `curl --tlsv1.2 https://tlstest.paypal.com/` returns `curl: (35) Unsupported SSL protocol version`.

Comment: @torek The instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataone/vignettes/known-issues.html) look promising to get back to a working version, but I will not try until tomorrow in case someone has another idea.

Comment: Please post the output of `devtools::session_info()` after an attempt to perform this operation to provide a bit more info about your system and R setup. I'd _highly_ suggest using homebrew to install a proper (Apple is terrible about some kinds of updates) version of curl/libcurl and then re-install the `curl` and `httr` packages. (if you do install homebrew, you shoudl also  run `brew update` and `brew upgrade` on a regular basis).

Comment: @hrbrmstr You cracked it!  `Homebrew` and formulae were already up to date, but re-installation in `R` of `curl` and/or `httr` fixed the problem.  I had run `update.packages` which should have hit these, but the fresh install did the job.  Thanks so much for the suggestion, this was a quite annoying issue.

Comment: @hrbrmstr If you like post as an answer or I can summarize in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly suggest using homebrew to install a proper (Apple is terrible about some kinds of updates) version of `curl`/`libcurl` and then re-install the `curl` and `httr` packages. (if you do install homebrew, you should also run `brew update` and `brew upgrade` on a regular basis).

Comment: I would just add that *re-installation* of `curl` and `httr` seemed to be the key, `update.packages` was not sufficient.